# C#: Pagination, Math.Ceiling

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

I'm creating some pagination and I'm getting an issue.

If I have a number 12 and I want to divide that by 5 (5 is the number of results I want on a page), how would I round it up properly? This doesn't work:

```
int total = 12;
int pages = Math.Ceiling(12 / 5);
//pages = 2.4... but I need it to be 3
```

Comment: How do you get pages to 2.4???? An `int` doesn't have decimals.

Comment: pages isn't actually 2.4 ... that equasion would be 2.4. That's the point...

Comment: Ok, so your problem is probably that you're not casting it to an int and handle the fact that int arithmetics always return in int. Se my answer in 2 sec.

Comment: @Tomas: casting Math.Ceiling(12/5) to int won't make a difference. It will still be 2 in stead of 3.

Comment: That's why it says "and handle the fact that int arithmetics always return in int"... maybe not obvious :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even though your code should work, `Math.Round` is wrong though, you could try this:

```
int pages = (total + pageSize - 1)/pageSize;
```

That should be the same as `Math.Ceiling` except that you are always dealing with `int` and not `double` at any point as `Math.Ceiling` returns.

**EDIT:** To get your code to work you could try:

```
int pages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)12/(double)5);
```

But you should use the first example.

Comment: Don't see the use of your edit. Doesn't the first line of code already provide the correct answer (3)?

Comment: Your example using `Math.Ceiling` won't actually compile. `Math.Ceiling` has overloads for `decimal` and `double`. Using it with an `int` will give you an ambiguous call error.

Comment: @Phil: Are you sure about that? Isn't there a implicit conversion from int to double? But I did update it to be more what he was doing.

Comment: There are implicit conversions from both `int` to `double` and `int` to `decimal`. The compiler won't know which of the two `Math.Ceiling` overloads to use.

Comment: @Phil: +1 Good to know... I rarely use this functions, it's not that hard to write your own:).

Answer (score 8):

you could do:

```
int numPages = Math.Ceiling((decimal)12 / (decimal)5);
```

or

```
int numPages = (12 + 4) / 5;  //(total + (perPage - 1)) / perPage
```

Comment: So even though 12 and 5 aren't decimals, I have to cast them as such?

Comment: If you don't, you'll do an integer divde on 12 by 5 resulting in 2. After that, you'll be trying to do Math.Ceiling on 2 witch will still be 2. The division goes before the Math.Ceiling. If you divide 12.0 by 5.0 you'll get 2.4 wich Math.Ceiling will turn into 3.  However, the second option is better, as Tomas Jansson explained.

Comment: @dcolumbus - yes.  int / int in C# always returns and int.  So, you need to cast them if you want decimals so that ceiling/rounding works as you expect it to.

Comment: `Math.Ceiling` isn't needed for the second version (and won't actually work since it only has overloads for `double` and `decimal`).

Comment: @Phil - his second version would have worked, but the `Ceiling` wasn't needed :)... I think at least.

Comment: @Tomas I meant that the second version wouldn't have compiled due to an ambiguous call error.